# Ways to merge specific columns from two dataset into a third dataset using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

Suppose i have two `Dataset ds1 & ds2` both holding data from two different `Tables`

```
Sql1 = "Select sTitle, sDate,active,color FROM TABLE1"
Sql2 = "Select eName, eDate FROM TABLE2"
```

What is the best way to merge these two `ds1, ds2` into a third dataset `ds3` with following columns
`EventTitle, BlockedDate` where I want to take `sTitle, sDate` from `ds1` and `eName, eDate`from `ds2`.

I need to know an approach which is fast, considering it is possible that each query may have up-to max of 200 rows

Actual sql1 is

```
;with Calendar as (
    select EventID, EventTitle, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventEnumDays,EventStartTime, EventRecurring, EventStartDate as PlannedDate
    ,EventType from EventCalender
    where EventActive = 1 AND LanguageID =1 AND EventBlockDate = 1 AND(  EventStartDate >= GETDATE() OR EventEndDate >= GETDATE() )
    union all
    select EventID, EventTitle, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventEnumDays,EventStartTime, EventRecurring, dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate)
    ,EventType from Calendar
    where (EventRecurring = 1
        and dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate) <= EventEndDate ) OR (EventRecurring = 0
        and dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate) <= EventEndDate) 
)
select EventID, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, PlannedDate as [EventDates], Cast(PlannedDate As datetime) +''+ Cast(EventStartTime As time) AS DT, EventTitle
,EventType from Calendar
where (PlannedDate >= GETDATE()) AND ',' + EventEnumDays + ',' like '%,' + cast(datepart(dw, PlannedDate) as char(1)) + ',%'
    AND PlannedDate <= DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())
    or EventEnumDays is null
order by EventID, PlannedDate
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should join it in the `query string` by using `join` or `Union`, rather than merging the `datatable`.

Comment: agree with you but in my case i am using bit complicate CTE queries to get the desired result. this is why i want to avoid UNION ... i have added the actual query to the question.